# jQuery & Rails 3 - callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, function, callback

I am trying to make my own confirm dialogs with two parameters.

```
function myAlert(message, adr) {
    jConfirm(message, 'Confirmation Dialog', function(answer) {
        if (answer){
            window.location = adr;
        }

    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.rails.confirm = function(mess, mess2) {
      return myAlert(mess, mess2);
  }
});
```

And in view:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', 
        {:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name'},
         :confirm => {"xxxxxxx", "aaaaaaaa"} %>
```

And in alert message I will get following:
**xxxxxxxaaaaaaaa**

What I am doing wrong? Why I don't get only **xxxxxxx**? Why are the strings merged?

PS: the first parameter in **jConfirm** function display the message to confirm window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `:confirm` is a string argument only. I'm a bit surprised, because `:confirm => {"xxxxxxx", "aaaaaaaa"}` should throw a syntax error if I'm not mistaken.

If you want to pass two parameters, you could store them in separate data attributes and roll your own confirmation method, something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', 
      :controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name', :class => "confirm",
      :data-foo => "bar", :data-bar => "foo" %>

$('a.confirm').click(function(){
  return myAlert($(this).data('foo'), $(this).data('bar'));
});
```

Or you comma-separate your arguments and split them using JS:

```
… :confirm => "foo,bar" …

$.rails.confirm = function(message) {
  var messageParts = message.split(',');
  return myAlert(messageParts[0], messageParts[1]);
}
```

Comment: stupid question - I am trying to do it by your first hint, but I am getting the error **undefined local variable or method `bar' for #<#<Class:0x1036b9f50>:0x1036b7bd8>** (I am newbie)

Comment: Try `:'data-foo'` instead of `:data-foo`.